# How to split javascript object of arrays into cumulative chunks?

Tags: javascript, split

This is a javascript problem.
I have data like this:

```
const data = {
'Testers' : ['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
'Developers' : ['G','H','I','J','K','L'],
'Designers' : ['M','N','O','P','Q','R']
}
```

Now I want this to split into chunks.

Use case:

Imagine I have to display their names in a page, and I have arrows to navigate between these.
In a page, I'll have,

```
Testers : 'A' - 'B' - 'C'
Developers : 'G' - 'H' - 'I'
Designers : 'M' - 'N' - 'O'
```

and then when I press next arrow, I have to be able to see

```
Testers : 'C' - 'D' - 'E' ( Dropping 'A' and 'B' to previous slide )
Developers : 'I' - 'J' - 'K' ( Dropping 'G' and 'H' to previous slide )
Designers : 'O' - 'P' - 'Q' ( Dropping 'M' and 'N' to previous slide )
```

So for this, I have to split the data into an array of chunks, like this,

```
const data = [
{
'Testers' : ['A','B','C'],
'Developers' : ['G','H','I'],
'Designers' : ['M','N','O']
}
,{
'Testers' : ['C','D','E'],
'Developers' : ['I','J','K'],
'Designers' : ['O','P','Q']
},{
'Testers' : ['D','E','F'],
'Developers' : ['J','K','L'],
'Designers' : ['P','Q','R']
}
]
```

Here assume page size = 3, slide changing offset = 2 and length of array in Testers, Developers, Designers will always be same.

Comment: Do all the arrays have same length?

Comment: Instead of splitting data into chunks, why not have a singular source of truth (your original data), and you simply increment a pointer based on which "window" you want to get? The window size will be 3 items, but the pointer starts with index of 0, then changes to 2, 4, and etc (multiples of 3 - 1)

Comment: @Terry I need to pass an array of objects. If it was like an index pointer change, I'd have preferred this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an array of length `Math.floor(data.Testers.length / pageOffset)` and then fill that with objects whose values are chunks of the input arrays; the indexes of the chunks are defined by the index of the array:

```js
const data = {
  'Testers': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
  'Developers': ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
  'Designers': ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R']
}

const pageSize = 3
const pageOffset = 2

const len = data.Testers.length

const result = Array.from({
    length: Math.floor(len / pageOffset)
  },
  (_, idx) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(data).map(([k, v]) => [k,
      v.slice(Math.min(idx * pageOffset, len - pageSize), Math.min(idx * pageOffset, len - pageSize) + pageSize)
    ])
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

Note we need to use `Math.min(idx * pageOffset, len - pageSize)` for the starting element of the slice to ensure the last slice also has `pageSize` entries.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling to get this result. A big thank you.

Comment: @HerraJohn I think I made a mistake in the length calculation; I should have used `floor` rather than `ceil`. Testing with some different numbers gave some incorrect results with `ceil`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you don't need to split your data in advance, just keep a single pointer and extract it on demand.

Note: you need to add to this code a length check for the last slice.

```
const SLIDEOFFSET=2;
const PAGESIZE=3;

function currentSlide(data,slidenum) {
  let result = {};
  for (const [key,value] of Object.entries(data)){
    result[key]=value.slice(slidenum*SLIDEOFFSET),slidenum*SLIDEOFFSET+PAGESIZE);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but I need to pass an array of objects. If it was like an index pointer change, I'd have preferred this way.